# provide execution rights on a certain code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

During the daily activity, many parameter activation or/and definition are required.
In order to not always ask for person with execute rights to do that, I am thinking that would be more easier to provide execute rights on the UPDATE/INSERT statement for that.

In order to achieve that, I am thinking to enclose the respective statement into a procedure/function, with parameters as the identifier of the row that will be updated/inserted and the list of values and provide the execute privileges on that procedure to all users which need it.

Is there any other approach in order to achieve that, please?

Thank you.

Comment: you could use a procedure, in which you control the parameters and then run the insert/update

Comment: In what way does the procedure you suggest not solve the problem you have?  It is vastly easier to suggest "other approaches" when we have some metrics on which to judge them.  I could suggest, for example, a small APEX application/ page (and/or Java, .Net, Python, etc.) that would provide a UI for users to execute the procedure.  That might be a reasonable option if you are concerned, say, that some users aren't going to have database logins or if there are complicated validations that need to be performed.  Not so much if the problem with a plain procedure is something else.

Comment: What is "daily activity"? What is "parameter activation and definition"? What is "execution rights"? Please recraft a question in which you show us sample code, or use standard Oracle terms so we can understand what you're trying to do.